# How to embed information into an NFT of its type/class?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, nft, erc-721, erc-1155

Let's say, I wanted to create an NFT collection such that there'll be 3 classes/types of NFTs: animals, humans and aliens.

For this, will I then have to simply introduce a field for `type` in a contract and it'll be it?

How would then a `type` variable be passed to the `constructor(...)` or perhaps to `mint(..)` properly in this case?

How is it usually implemented **in the case of NFT?**

---

ERC1155 or ERC721

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends.

This kind of things can either be at the contract level or in the metadata. Metadata is the data which is usually pointed at with an URI inside the contract, and the metadata contents depend on the NFT unique ID.

If the type is added at contract level, you probably have three different contracts: one for each type. So when minting an *animal NFT* you call the minting in the *AnimalNFT.sol* or whatever it's called.

You *can* also add it as a field inside the contract, but that kind of logic is not supported in external integrations. For example, if you want to sell the NFT in Opensea, I don't think they check if there is a *type* field since it's not part of the standard.